# How to authenticate to oauth2-proxy via cURL or POSTMAN

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2-proxy

I have my service set behind [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) and I am using version 4.0.0.

I am trying to hit an API behind the service, but unfortunately, I always get a `403 forbidden` error because of oauth2-proxy being in the way.

I am looking for a way to authenticate via g-suite using `oauth2-proxy` and generate a token that I can then use for the service.

Does `oauth2-proxy` support any kind of way to authenticate via cURL or POST call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels to me that your deployment separation is not right. OAuth has a strong focus on separation of web and API concerns. The `oauth2-proxy` utility is a web client and should not be deployed in front of APIs since that can limit your options.

**SUBOPTIMAL DEPLOYMENT**

- API is hosted behind oauth2-proxy
- oauth2-proxy issues redirects to the browser
- Browser clients can handle redirects and users can login
- After a browser login oauth2-proxy issues a cookie
- oauth2-proxy translates cookies to tokens when JavaScript calls APIs
- Mobile apps or API test clients cannot call the API

**OPTIMIZED DEPLOYMENT**

- Web static content is hosted behind oauth2-proxy
- oauth2-proxy issues redirects to the browser
- Browser clients can handle redirects and users can login
- After a browser login oauth2-proxy issues a cookie
- oauth2-proxy translates cookies to tokens when JavaScript calls APIs
- APIs have their own internet entry points that require access tokens
- Mobile apps or API test clients can call APIs with an access token

If I'm misunderstanding anything, maybe clarify your question and post back.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Entra IdP, I faced a similar situation. Here I logged in using SSO in web-browser. Noted down the `Bearer Token` or `_oauth2_proxy` in cookies. And passed this in cUrl or Postman.
For Gsuite, I believe cookies with names similar to this `__Secure-3PSID` contains the value required for verifying ot OAuth Level, that this request is authenticated.

So note down these cookies values and pass it in cUrl or Postman, along with your normal request to respected service. Hopefully that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first :

- Make a request to be redirected to IDP authentication.
- Authenticate to your IDP.
- Request the token from the callback URL
- Then authenticate using the token. (Probably as a bearer token)

I hope this article helps you understand better how to authenticate with an IDP.